# Does Redisson support RPriorityBlockingQueue in Cluster-Mode?

Tags: redisson

When I try to use RPriorityBlockingQueue in cluster-mode, I get some lock errors.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: None of slaves were synced. Try to increase slavesSyncTimeout setting or set checkLockSyncedSlaves = false.
```

and my code looks like:

```
RedissonClient redissonClient = ...;
...
redissonClient.getPriorityBlockingQueue(queueName, codec).offer(data);
```

Am I missing something? or RPriorityBlockingQueue doesn't work on cluster-mode?